# Number of repeats

Tags: ruby, algorithm

> Write a method that takes in a string and returns the number of letters that appear more than once in the string. You may assume the string contains only lowercase letters. Count the number of letters that repeat, not the number of times they repeat in the string.

I implemented methods and test cases as:

```
def num_repeats(string)
  count = 0
  dix = 0
  new = ""
  while dix < string.length
    letter = string[dix]
    if !(new.include?(letter))
      new = new + "letter"
    else
      break
    end
    dix2 = dix + 1
    while dix2 < string.length
      if letter == string[dix2]
        count +=1
        break
      end
      dix2 +=1
    end
    dix += 1
  end
     puts(count.to_s)
  return count


end

# These are tests to check that your code is working. After writing
# your solution, they should all print true.

puts('num_repeats("abdbc") == 1: ' + (num_repeats('abdbc') == 1).to_s)
# one character is repeated
puts('num_repeats("aaa") == 1: ' + (num_repeats('aaa') == 1).to_s)
puts('num_repeats("abab") == 2: ' + (num_repeats('abab') == 2).to_s)
puts('num_repeats("cadac") == 2: ' + (num_repeats('cadac') == 2).to_s)
puts('num_repeats("abcde") == 0: ' + (num_repeats('abcde') == 0).to_s)
```

Test results:

```
1                                                                                                                                                                                      
num_repeats("abdbc") == 1: true                                                                                                                                                        
2                                                                                                                                                                                      
num_repeats("aaa") == 1: false                                                                                                                                                         
2                                                                                                                                                                                      
num_repeats("abab") == 2: true                                                                                                                                                         
2                                                                                                                                                                                      
num_repeats("cadac") == 2: true                                                                                                                                                        
0                                                                                                                                                                                      
num_repeats("abcde") == 0: true
```

For the second test that returned false, what was wrong with my code?

Comment: I must admit your code is so incredibly complex that I don't understand any of it. However, line 8 looks extremely suspicious. But, what's wrong with a simple `def num_repeats(str) str.chars.group_by(&:itself).count {|_, ary| ary.size > 1 } end`?

Comment: Edited title and tags since question is a general Ruby question and does not have any real connection to Rails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are appending `"letter"`, rather than the `letter` variable to `new` on line 8.

```
if !(new.include?(letter))
  new = new + "letter"
else
  #...
end
```

becomes:

```
unless new.include?(letter)
  new = new + letter
else
  #...
end
```

Comment: Also if you want to get the number of repeated letters you can simply do `str.scan(/./).length - str.scan(/./).uniq.length`

Comment: Technically, you're right. Pedantically, the question was 'what is wrong with my code?' not 'Whats the best way to do this?'